# How to host SPA files and embed too with axum and rust-embed

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I'm having hard time understanding how to embed SPA (single page application) files with `rust-embed` and `axum`.

I have no trouble without `rust-embed` using a single line of code with `axum` ([from here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/static-file-server/src/main.rs)):

```rust
app.fallback(get_service(ServeDir::new("./app/static")).handle_error(error_handler))
```

It works because all files are correctly downloaded. But:

#### FIRST PROBLEM

What is missing for a properly SPA handling is the redirect on the `index.html` if for example the user reloads the page on a SPA nested route.

Example: I'm on the page: `/home/customers` which is not a file nor a dir but just a fake javascript route and if I reload the page axum gives me `404` (Not found).

#### SECOND PROBLEM

I need to embed those files in my final executable. In Golang this is "native" using `embed:` directive.

I saw that in Rust this is well done with `rust-embed` but I cannot complete my task for SPA.

The need is that every path typed by the user (and that is not an existent file such as `.js` or `.css` which obviously must be downloaded by the browser) leads to the "`index.html`" file in the root of my `static` dir.

If I use [the example axum code](https://github.com/pyrossh/rust-embed/blob/master/examples/axum.rs) I can see the route:

```rust
.route("/dist/*file", static_handler.into_service())
```

which has `/dist/*file` and I don't need that `/dist` because the `index.html` calls many files with custom paths, such as `/_works`, `menu`, `images`.

If I remove the `dist` part I get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Invalid route: insertion failed due to conflict with previously registered route: /index.html'
```

Can you help me understand how to properly accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey :) I had the same issue. added a comment in the discussion on a similar topic in the axum repo https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/1309

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, building with Vue and Axum/Rust.
Here's how I solved Problem one

1. Install the `tower_http` crate
2. use `axum::routing::get_service` to serve the build SPA.

```rust
//example implementation 
...
   //static file mounting
    let assets_dir = PathBuf::from(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).join("views");
    let static_files_service = get_service(
        ServeDir::new(assets_dir).append_index_html_on_directories(true),
    )
    .handle_error(|error: std::io::Error| async move {
        (
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            format!("Unhandled internal error: {}", error),
        )
    });
...
```

3. Mount the static file rendering

```rust
  //mount the app routes and middleware
    let app = Router::new()
        .fallback(static_files_service)
        .nest("/api/v1/", routes::root::router())
        .layer(cors)
        .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http())
        .layer(Extension(database));
```

Check out the full source code [here](https://github.com/opeolluwa/nitride). Another thing is, Axum seems to have breaking changes in subsequent versions as I found out [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/http-request-validation-for-axum-web-framework/82736), so you might need to check the doc/example that corresponds to the version of Axum you are using :)